# Using intern unit test case for dojo 1.7.2 project

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, intern

Followed the tutorial for intern module and installed i.e `npm install intern --save-dev` .
Copied intern node module to the project workspace so that browser based intern testing was meant to be used. 
Copied the test html page provided in node module and set path for packages as mentioned. 
Created test widget and test case for it as per tutorial.
Finally tested it with test html page but there was class loader problem since I specified dojo version 1.7.2 for packages. 
If tried with 1.9.1, it works. The actual error was it required modules such as dojo/promise that doesn't exist with 1.7.2 version. 
I am stuck with this version conflict and need to know whether intern is compatible with Dojo 1.7.2 or not.
Else is there a way to write intern test case for older version of Dojo ?

Help on this!

Comment: What test html page are you referring to? You shouldn’t ever be copying anything except for the configuration file out of the Intern package. If you are referring to `client.html`, you absolutely should *not* be copying or touching that file in any way.

Comment: I copied client.html that u mentioned and thought it will be the test runner in browser. What is the correct way of using intern with my existing application. kindly guide!

Comment: @CSnover , Thanks for the help.. Referred your tutorial and configured proper.. Dojo testing worked fine for older version (1.7)